# Get updated tags of html in chromeDriver using selenium after click in C#

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests, c#-5.0, automation-testing

Working on Selenium automation testing after a click on button <ViewStatement> webpage gets updated with pdf link and some other tags but it is not updating into ChromeDriver driver object

I already tried like PageSource & hit same url into another ChromeDriver driver1 but still not working.

link - https://mfs.kfintech.com/

Code -

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value='View Statement']")).Click();
```

before this click the page is completely loaded into the driver but after click page doesn't reloaded but still some tags are inserted into the same page with same link before and after click so i want whole page after click.

ViewStatement does not exist on link page after login it is there.

Comment: //input[@value='View Statement'] selector doesn't exist

Comment: The element `//input[@value='View Statement']` doesn't seems to be available on the page https://mfs.kfintech.com/mfs/

Comment: [Link](https://mfs.kfintech.com/) this link is of login page but viewStatement button is on the ViewStatement.aspx page I reach that page just not getting updated page after click

Comment: That webpage does not contain the element - //input[@value='View Statement'], post your complete code and explain what exactly are you expecting?

Comment: viewStatement button is on another page it come after login